# How do I Activate a Product Key in Desura?

Tags: desura

I've recently started using Desura.  I absolutely *love* it except for one thing; the user interface isn't always very user-friendly.  Where do I go to activate a product key?

UPDATE: Desura is currently shut-down.

Comment: "the menus aren't very user friendly" welcome to every open source project :P

Comment: [__desura.com/gifts__](http://www.desura.com/gifts)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To activate a product key:

- open the Desura client
- click the Desura logo in the upper left corner
- click Tools
- click "Activate game CD key or gift"

In the window that opens up, you will be able to enter the key that you have, and then all you need to do is click "Activate", and it will activate your product key.

Answer (score 18):

You can also do it via this url: http://www.desura.com/gifts

Answer (score 5):

Desura also lets you do this without going through the client.

You can visit http://www.desura.com/ and scroll to the bottom and under the `PLAY` menu, select `Gifts`, which brings you to http://www.desura.com/gifts.  From here you can see any gifts you've given your friends on Desura, and also activate a product key.

[image]